# speed up an update join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have 2 tables each of one hundred million rows, with key1 and str_key both non-unique keys.
the following MYSQL query, according to show engine innodb status, is performing around 80 reads/sec, no updates yet.  No other query is running.

```
 update table_r r, table_w w set r.key1=0 where r.str_key=w.str_key
```

1. is it correct that the query would take 100 million / 60  > 1 million seconds to finish?
2. how do I optimize the query to finish quickly?

Comment: Try add an index on column `table_r.str_key` and `table_w.str_key`

Comment: key1 and str_key are both keys already, so they are indexed

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a query is slow, the first thing to do is make sure you have an index on all columns mentioned in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You must index your WHERE clause fields in tables, and with one hundred million rows you should partion your table, if you do it properly, all of your query perform much quickly.

This [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html) may helps you.

> From a performance standpoint, the main take-away is that MySQL 5.1
>   partitioning is a powerful new tool that can be used in many physical
>   database designs to dramatically improve performance and ease DBA
>   management burdens. For more information on MySQL partitioning, you
>   can visit out the online reference manual at
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html and visit the
>   MySQL forums as there is a forum section devoted to partitioning,
>   which can be referenced at http://forums.mysql.com/list.php?106.

Comment: the columns in where clause are both keys, so they are already indexed, right?